# How to copy a sheet and ensure it is at the end of all other sheets?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

```
sheetCopy.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

I use the code above to create a copy of a template worksheet in Excel.

Most of the time it creates the tab at the end which is what I want but sometime it creates new tab somewhere in the middle.

Is there a way to ensure it is copied to the end of the sheets?

Comment: ```Worksheets.Count``` has no reference it will use whatever the active workbook is.

Comment: You mean I should use ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count) ?

Comment: Yes, that should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`(Thisworkbook.Worksheets.Count)`

Answer (score 1):

### The issue

When working with a `Workbook`, `Worksheet`, `Range`, or other similar objects, it's best to [avoid implicit member calls](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/10/25/clean-vba-code-pt-2-avoiding-implicit-code/).

Most of these default to whatever is active. For instance, `Worksheets.count` is the same as `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count`.

In your code you were almost there as you correctly used `ThisWorkbook` when accessing the `Worksheets` Collection; however, the `Worksheets.count` is defaulting to the `ActiveWorkbook`.

### The Solution

To fix it, I like using `With` blocks to help shorten the code, and make it easier to be explicit in my refrences.

```vb
With ThisWorkbook
    sheetCopy.Copy After:=.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count)
End With
```